# Why is the /paths endpoint on my custom Horizon deployment abnormally slow?

Tags: horizon, paths, path-payment

I was wondering if anyone has an idea what could be causing our Horizon (0.17.6) `/paths` endpoint to be extremely slow.

A simple query takes 1m22s on our custom deployment. On public SDF Horizon the same query takes only 3.8s.

**Custom deployment**

```
[root@horizon ~]# time curl -s -o /dev/null "localhost:8000/paths?source_account=GCO2IP3MJNUOKS4PUDI4C7LGGMQDJGXG3COYX3WSB4HHNAHKYV5YL3VC&destination_account=GCO2IP3MJNUOKS4PUDI4C7LGGMQDJGXG3COYX3WSB4HHNAHKYV5YL3VC&destination_asset_type=native&destination_asset_code=XLM&destination_asset_issuer=&destination_amount=0.1"

real    1m21.546s
```

**Public SDF**

```
[root@horizon ~]# time curl -s -o /dev/null "https://horizon.stellar.org/paths?source_account=GCO2IP3MJNUOKS4PUDI4C7LGGMQDJGXG3COYX3WSB4HHNAHKYV5YL3VC&destination_account=GCO2IP3MJNUOKS4PUDI4C7LGGMQDJGXG3COYX3WSB4HHNAHKYV5YL3VC&destination_asset_type=native&destination_asset_code=XLM&destination_asset_issuer=&destination_amount=0.1"

real    0m3.814s
```

**This is my my Horizon configuration**

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/horizon --stellar-core-url=http://stellar-core-server.com:11626 --port=8000 --per-hour-rate-limit=1000000 --max-db-connections=250 --sse-update-frequency=1 --connection-timeout=60 --log-level=info --log-file=/var/log/horizon.log --ingest=true --history-retention-count=0 --history-stale-threshold=0 --enable-asset-stats=false --max-path-length=3
```

As you can see I lowered `--max-path-length` to 3 already. With 2 it works very fast 0.332s but this isn't really desirable. With the default setting (4) it's taking more than three minutes (and at that point I canceled).

I noticed that there isn't any activity in Postgresql for most of the time while the endpoint is being invoked so maybe the problem is somewhere else.

**Active SQL queries while endpoint is busy for 1m22s:**

```
postgres=# SELECT datname,pid,query FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY pid ;
 datname  | pid  |                                           query
----------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 horizon  | 2416 | SELECT * FROM gorp_migrations
 horizon  | 2430 | SELECT * FROM gorp_migrations
 horizon  | 2433 |                                                                                          +
          |      |                 SELECT base_fee, sequence                                                +
          |      |                 FROM history_ledgers                                                     +
          |      |                 WHERE sequence = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(sequence), 0) FROM history_ledgers)+
          |      |
 horizon  | 2440 | SELECT COALESCE(MAX(sequence), 0) FROM history_ledgers
 horizon  | 2441 | SELECT COALESCE(MAX(sequence), 0) FROM history_ledgers
 horizon  | 2442 | SELECT COALESCE(MIN(sequence), 0) FROM history_ledgers
 postgres | 2644 | SELECT datname,pid,query FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY pid ;
```

None of these seem relevant to `/paths`.

I know that there are efforts to move the query into memory (https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/849), which should speed things up considerably but this might still take a while and I am at a loss about what is going on. Any hints appreciated. Thank you!